# laravel morphToMany of parent model how to use in subquery?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Current laravel models relations: `ParentModel` can have many documents, `ChildModel` can have many documents, same `Documents` can be belonged to any of `ParentModel` and `ChildModel`.
Also `ChildModel` always belongs to one `ParentModel`. `ParentModel` can have multiple `ChildModels`.

App\ParentModel relationships

```
...
public function childmodels()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ChildModel');
} 
public function documents() 
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\Document', 'documentable');
}
...
```

App\ChildModel relationships

```
...
public function parentmodel()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\ParentModel');
}
public function documents() 
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\Document', 'documentable');
}
...
```

App\Document

```
...
public function parentmodels()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\ParentModel','documentable');
}    

public function childmodels()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\ChildModel','documentable');
}
...
```

Now I'm trying to get all records of `ChildModels` (1) which have documents with specific type and (2) its `ParentModel` can also have documents.

The (1) first goal can be reached with such `ChildModel` method.

```
/* checking GET param to join this condition to final query */
if($request->has('report') && $request->input('report') == 'on') {

    /* get all documents related to CurrentModel */
    $query->whereHas('documents',function (Builder $query) {
        $query->where('type', 1);
    });        

}
```

But this obviously doesnt include records of `ChildModels`, `ParentModel` of which has documents with specific type.

So the question is: how to include such condition into `ChildModel` query builder?

Comment: Does it help you to know that relationships can be called and used 2 different ways?  $model->relationship will return as a result set.  $model->relationshp() with parentheses will return a query builder.  So you can add sql to that builder $model->relationship()->where(...)

Comment: Not helpful, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Found the easy way to access relations in builder

```
$query->whereHas('parentmodels.documents', function(Builder $query){
     $query->where('type',1);
});
```